# Laravel Login Keeps Giving Unauthenticated Exception Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I've been working on a new Login Controller for another type of user called Super User for this project at work. I've been making the controller and all the additional files attached to it based on this project I found on [github](https://github.com/weeework/laravel55multiauth)

So I created the controller and added and modified all the necessary files, no problem there, it even, technically undertands that I'm using the new guard. But then a problem arose. Right as I was testing the login, no matter how many times I try it always redirects me back to the login page (which in this case it's also the index for the sub-page.

The weird thing is that A) Laravel doesn't throw me any errors whatsoever and B) It logs in when I reset my password through the forgot password controller (I assume because of the functionality that makes it auto-log in once you reset it)

I've been searching like crazy for answers for the last few days but can't find anything that quite resembles my problem. My suspicion is that it has something to do with the way I modified either the Exception Handler or the login function in LoginController since the logout function works without any problems. It also executes the password reset without any issues so that means that the Guard I created for the user was configured correctly.

I also know that it's reading from the right database because it manages to login with the super user's credentials once the password resets.

Hopefully someone can help me, here's the code for the super user LoginController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Super\AuthSuper;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{


/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
//protected $redirectTo = '/home'; 

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest:super')->except('logout');
}

public function showIndex(){
    return view('caja.sucursal');
}

public function login(Request $request)
   {
       $this->validate($request, [
           'email' => 'required|email',
           'password' => 'required|min:6'
       ]);

       $credential = [
           'email' => $request->email,
           'password' => $request->password
       ];

       // Attempt to log the user in
       if (guard()->attempt($credential)){
           // If login succesful, then redirect to their intended location
           return redirect()->intended(route('caja.home'));
       }

       // If Unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form 
  data
       return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
   }


public function logout(){
    Auth::guard('super')->logout();
    return redirect('/sucursal')->with('flash','Se ha cerrado la Sesión');;
}




public function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('super');
}
}
```

As you can see, here I assign it the guard 'super' and then use that to check if the user that's trying to log in has it, if they do and the credentials are correct then it should send them to the home page.

Here's a snippet from the auth.php file where I declare the guard 'super'

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'super' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'supers',
    ],

    'api-super' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'supers',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'supers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Superuser::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
 ],

 'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'supers' => [
        'provider' => 'supers',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

Here's the modified redirect if authenticated function where I declare the 'super' guard

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    switch ($guard){
        case 'super':
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect()->route('caja.home');
            }
            break;

        default:
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect()->route('home');
            }
            break;
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

And here's who I believe to be the main culprit of the whole thing. Handler.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Request;
use Response;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
/**
 * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dontReport = [
    //
];

/**
 * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dontFlash = [
    'password',
    'password_confirmation',
];

/**
 * Report or log an exception.
 *
 * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return void
 */
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    parent::report($exception);
}

/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    // if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException){
    //     return redirect('/')->with('flash','Por favor Inicia Sesión');
    // }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}

protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
//        return $request->expectsJson()
//            ? response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401)
//            : redirect()->guest(route('login'));

    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    $guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);
    switch ($guard) {
        case 'super':
            $login = 'caja.sucursal';
            break;

        default:
            $login = '/';
            break;
    }
    return redirect()->guest(route($login))->with('flash','Por favor Inicia Sesión');
}
}
```

I don't know how useful it'll be but here are the snippets from the ForgetPasswordController and ResetPasswordController that I made for the super user.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Super\AuthSuper;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{


use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest:super');
}

public function broker()
{
    return Password::broker('supers');
}


/**
 * Display the form to request a password reset link.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showLinkRequestForm()
{
    return view('authSuper.passwords.email');
}

/**
 * Send a reset link to the given user.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateEmail($request);

    // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
    // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
    // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
        $request->only('email')
    );

    return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
        ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
        : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
}


}
```

-

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Super\AuthSuper;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{

use ResetsPasswords;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/sucursal';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest:super');
}

public function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('super');
}

public function broker()
{
    return Password::broker('supers');
}

/**
 * Display the password reset view for the given token.
 *
 * If no token is present, display the link request form.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  string|null  $token
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    return view('authSuper.passwords.reset')->with(
        ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
    );
}
}
```

To close off here's a snippet of the view that's supposed to access the login function of the controller:

```
<form role="form" action="{{ route('caja.login')}}" method="POST">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('rut') ? 'has-error':''}}">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="r-form-1-name">RUT</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="rut" placeholder="Rut..." class="r-form-1-name form-control" id="r-form-1-name" value="{{ old('rut')}}">
                                    {!! $errors->first('rut','<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'has-error':''}}">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="r-form-1-email">CONTRASEÑA</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña..." class="r-form-1-email form-control" id="r-form-1-email">
                                    {!! $errors->first('password','<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
                                </div>

                                <p class="terms">
                                    * Olvidaste la Contraseña? 
                                    <!--<a href="#" class="launch-modal" 
   data-modal-id="modal-terms">Presiona aquí</a>-->
                                    <a href="{{ 
  route('caja.password.resetter') }}">Presiona aquí</a>
                                </p>
                                <center>
                                    <a class="btn" href=" 
   {{route('caja.home')}}">ENTRAR</a>
                                </center>

                            </form>
```

And the routes assigned to the sub-site that the super user is supposed to access (including the routes for the login page and such:

```
 Route::prefix('sucursal')->group(function(){
Route::get('/', 'Super\AuthSuper\LoginController@showIndex')->name('caja.sucursal');
Route::get('/home','Super\CajaController@home')->name('caja.home');
Route::post('/login', 'Super\AuthSuper\LoginController@login')->name('caja.login');
Route::post('/logout', 'Super\AuthSuper\LoginController@logout')->name('caja.logout');
Route::get('/password/reset', 'Super\AuthSuper\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('caja.password.resetter');
Route::post('/password/email', 'Super\AuthSuper\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('caja.password.email');
 Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'Super\AuthSuper\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('caja.password.reset');
 Route::post('/password/request', 'Super\AuthSuper\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('caja.password.request');
 Route::post('buscar-rut', 'Super\CajaController@buscarRut');
 });
```

I know that it's a lot, but I've done everything short of just completely redoing everything again (which I'm still going to do, not gonna lie), but all my searching has proved fruitless. I'm sure that there must be something small that I'm missing even if it's right before my eyes but it just keeps up eluding me.

Comment: What was the solution?